# Will a memory module with 16-16-16 timing work correctly with one having 16-16-16-39?

Tags: memory, desktop-computer, computer-building

I have 2x8GB memory in my PC at the moment, this model: https://www.newegg.com/ballistix-8gb-288-pin-ddr4-sdram/p/N82E16820148983
I'd like to get another 2x8GB. I was trying to find a kit which has exactly the same parameters, I found this one: https://www.newegg.com/corsair-16gb-288-pin-ddr4-sdram/p/N82E16820233970

The speed (2400Mhz), voltage (1.2V), CAS latency (16) are the same. The only difference is that the timing value of my current modules in their spec is "16-16-16", and for the new ones it's "16-16-16-39". (And this was the case also for any other model I've found which are available today.)
Can this difference cause a problem, or the two kits are supposed to work well together regardless?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From
[Wikipedia Memory timings](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_timings),
these four measures are `CL- tRCD – tRP – tRAS`:

**CL**: Column address strobe (CAS) latency is the time it takes
between the processor asking memory for data and memory
returning it.

**tRCD**: Row address strobe (RAS) to CAS delay is the time it
takes between the activation of the row (RAS) and the column
(CAS) where data is stored in the matrix.

**tRP**: RAS precharge is the time between disabling the access
to a row of data and the beginning of the access to another
row of data.

**tRAS**: Active to precharge delay is how long the memory has
to wait until the next access to memory can be initiated.

From the fact that the first three parameters are identical means already
that the memory is very similar. The tRAS parameter is not specified, but
it is unlikely that it is drastically different.

It is highly likely that the motherboard will adjust to a small difference
(if it even exists), but of course there is never any guarantee when the sticks
are not identical.

Comment: Thanks, probably then I will go with it, and try if it works.

Comment: Just an update: it works fine :)

Answer (score 1):

If the voltages are the same, the best course of action is to manually set the timings in the BIOS to that of the slowest pair.